# Angular 1.x dynamically change element's width using user input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-style

I'm creating dynamically an element that I need to have control over its width and position. I'm trying to change its style using an `input` with `ng-model` and `ng-style` directive in the created element, in the following manner:
JS:

```
function createElementAndAppend(){
    element = angular.element("<"+element+" id='inputTag' ng-click='selectClickedElm($event.currentTarget)' ng-style='{width: w + 'px'} placeholder='input'>");
    angular.element(document.getElementById('board')).append($compile(element)($scope));
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="w" placeholder="change width">
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Error: [$parse:ueoe] Unexpected end of expression: {width: w
```

Obviously the problem is with `ng-style='{width: w + 'px'}`. How do I write the plus sign to angular will know to interpret the value of `w` with `px` as thw final width of the element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tested it, but this should work:

```
element = angular.element("<"+element+" id='inputTag' ng-click='selectClickedElm($event.currentTarget)' ng-style='{width: w + \"px\"}' placeholder='input'>");
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed.